# changing contents of a button programmatically

Tags: wpf, button, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have a button called btnLogin, and I wish to change the contents of this button when a variable changes.  Basically I have a login screen, and once the user logs in successfully, I am setting a variable, and according to this variable, I wish the contents to change.

So at the moment I have a Login Screen and upon login, i am setting this variable:-

```
        ApplicationState.SetValue("UserLoggedIn", "True");
```

Then in the main screen, I have this piece of code when the Window is Loaded :-

```
    private void CheckLoginButton()
    {
        //check if user is checked in or out
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ApplicationState.GetValue<string>("UserLoggedIn")))
        {
            //User not logged in
            ImageSource largeImageSource =
                new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/myAppWPF;component/Images/administrator-icon32.png", UriKind.Relative));
            ImageSource smallImageSource =
                new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/myAppWPF;component/Images/administrator-icon16.png", UriKind.Relative));
            btnLogin.LargeImageSource = largeImageSource;
            btnLogin.SmallImageSource = smallImageSource;
            btnLogin.Label = "Login";
            btnLogin.ToolTipTitle = "Please Log In";

        }
        else
        {
            //User logged in
            ImageSource largeImageSource =
                new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/myAppWPF;component/Images/logout32.png", UriKind.Relative));
            ImageSource smallImageSource =
                new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/myAppWPF;component/Images/logout16.png", UriKind.Relative));
            btnLogin.LargeImageSource = largeImageSource;
            btnLogin.SmallImageSource = smallImageSource;
            btnLogin.Label = "Log Out";
            btnLogin.ToolTipTitle = "Log Out";
        }
    }
```

and in the XAML I have the following :-

```
<r:RibbonGroup Name="AdminGroup" Header="Admin" >
    <r:RibbonButton Name="btnLogin" Click="btnLogin_Click" ></r:RibbonButton>
</r:RibbonGroup>
```

However, everytime, the btnLogin is always set to Login and never to Logout, even if the variable is set correctly.

Do I need to register this button again?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: Is the window loaded before or after the login?

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this in WPF is by using the Model-View-ViewModel pattern. Read more about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johngossman/archive/2005/10/08/478683.aspx)

Basically you have to create a class (the ViewModel) that will notify your button (the View) that it must change its contents when UserLoggedIn (the Model) changes. This class must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and trigger the PropertyChanged event when the value of UserLoggedIn changes thus the UI changes accordingly. So you should almost never reference your button (btnLogin) from code, instead, the button should be data bound to a variable in your ViewModel object from XAML and get notified when it changes.

The beauty of using this pattern is that you will be using a declarative approach for most of the logic, using data binding and triggers and that the UI logic will be separate from your business logic. If you're new to WPF I suggest you read about the MVVM pattern first as it will save you **a lot** of time in the long run.

The logic you show there performs exactly the same task a trigger would perform but you're probably mixing business code with UI code (i.e. you have a class that manages both the login **and** knows about which picture to show when the user is logged in).

However, if you want to stick with your design. I'm guessing the problem is that your only running that code once ("I have this piece of code when the Window is Loaded"), and you should run CheckLoginButton when the user logs in, or more precisely, when the UserLoggedIn value changes to true or false.

Comment: Hi Juan, thanks for your reply.  Yes I need to read and study about the MVVM pattern, however at the moment i am building a small app just to get accustomed to WPF.  I have the code in the contructor yes.  And I have the loginscreen as an instance.  So when I close the "Login" window, control is passed back to the Main constructor and I have checked that the variable is set correctly and that the correct piece of code is executed.  However, everything remains the same! so I was thinking maybe I need to refresh something for it to work

Comment: Have you solved this problem? As I understand it, you have two windows: a main window and a log-in window, am I right? There's a chance that the problem is in the control you're using (i.e. r:RibbonButton), is this a custom control you created? Does it have a ControlTemplate?